# Program Right-Click Methods in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm working on the Revit API, and I'd like to be able to program some function off the `Right-Click` rather than inserting another button and dialog window.  Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?  Any help, links, etc. is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some in-depth Google'ing, I found this:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/is-context-menu-accessible-through-api/td-p/3228382

Turns out, Revit (and Autodesk in general) does not allow developer access to the context menus.  That makes me a sad panda.  Thanks for your help @peterpep.